# Read string and integer from a file using fscanf

Tags: c, file

I am having a structure like this

```
struct tm1
{
    char buf[80];
    int val;
} pl;
```

I want to fill this structure from a file and the file contains current time and one value. Like this

```
Mon Dec  4 19:36:23 2017 98
```

Now I want to do fscanf of time and the value i.e 98 from the file and put those values in the structure (time should go to the structure member buf and the value i.e. 98 should go to the structure member val.)

Now the problem is fscanf terminates at first white space, so to resolve this I tried

```
 fscanf(infile,"%[^\n]",pl.buf);
```

but after doing this value 98 from the file also going to structure member buf..

How can I store time in structure member buf and the value 98 in structure member val ?

Comment: You know how to read the whole line; you don't see any way to extract & remove the trailing number from that line?

Comment: USe `fgets` and parse the string yourself.

Comment: @David -- Thanks for the response, yes I want to store entire date in the structure member buf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best to use `fgets()` to fetch lines of input. Then `sscanf()` could be used to parse the input.

You can combine assignment suppression (`*`) with a scanset directive (`%[]`) to ignore the first part of the date: `%*[^0-9] %*d`. Scan the time, then use suppression again to ignore the year. Note that the behavior of a dash in a scanset, e.g. `%*[^0-9]` is implementation-defined, but this commonly behaves as expected to indicate a range. A completely portable alternative would be to use: `%*[^0123456789]` instead.

Here is an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tm1
{
    char buf[80];
    int val;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct tm1 p1;

    FILE *fp = fopen("file.dat", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to open file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[4096];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp)) {
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%*[^0-9] %*d %79s %*d %d", p1.buf, &p1.val) == 2) {
            printf("%s, %d\n", p1.buf, p1.val);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
19:36:23, 98
```

### Update

I appear to have misunderstood OP's question. The above solution does not store the entire date in the `buf` field of the `struct`. In order to store the entire date, it would be nice to have some delimiter between the date and the final value to help in parsing input lines. In absence of such a delimiter, the techniques mentioned above may still be useful.

The `%n` directive stores the number of characters read from the input stream so far when it is encountered. This can be used to identify the location following the date in the example input. Consider:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%*[^0123456789] %*d %*s %*d%n", &tail)
```

Here `sscanf()` ignores each of the date components, and stores the character count in `tail`, which amounts to the index of the character following the date in `buffer[]`. `sscanf()` can be used again to get the final value by scanning:

```
sscanf(buffer + tail, "%d", &p1.val)
```

Then a null-terminator can be placed after the date, allowing the date to be copied to the appropriate field of the `struct`.

Here is another example program. The parsing is not bullet-proof here, but it should handle well-formatted data. Note that when `tail` is too large, the line is skipped. This indicates that the date string would not fit into `p1.buf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct tm1
{
    char buf[80];
    int val;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct tm1 p1;

    FILE *fp = fopen("file.dat", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to open file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[4096];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp)) {
        int tail = 0;
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%*[^0123456789] %*d %*s %*d%n", &tail) == 0) {
            if ((unsigned) tail < sizeof p1.buf
                && sscanf(buffer + tail, "%d", &p1.val) == 1) {
                buffer[tail] = '\0';
                strcpy(p1.buf, buffer);
                printf("%s, %d\n", p1.buf, p1.val);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a sample input file:

```
Mon Dec  4 19:36:23 2017 98
Tues Dec  5 19:36:28 2017 99
Wed Dec  6 19:36:21 2017 95
Thur Dec  7 19:36:23 2017 89
Fri Dec  8 19:36:20 2017 93
Sat Dec  9 19:36:22 2017 oops! 95
Sun Dec  10 19:36:23 2017 98
Sun               Dec                      10                   19:36:23                     2017 98
Mon Dec  11 19:36:25 2017 97
```

And here is the program output:

```
Mon Dec  4 19:36:23 2017, 98
Tues Dec  5 19:36:28 2017, 99
Wed Dec  6 19:36:21 2017, 95
Thur Dec  7 19:36:23 2017, 89
Fri Dec  8 19:36:20 2017, 93
Sun Dec  10 19:36:23 2017, 98
Mon Dec  11 19:36:25 2017, 97
```